# hide information from webmasters who using codes to extract information in webpage using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, encryption, encoding

I working on a property website. we have house information in it but some other sites collect our information and insert in their site. how can i show the information in browser but not to robots which using functions to collect information automatically?

Pleas note: I don't mean the search engines, i mean the webmasters who using codes to extract information by reading the content that i publish using functions like get_file_content(url)...

one way may be some kind of codding the content using javascript/vbscript because in my case the developer uses last html output...

Comment: Scrapers will not follow the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

In your website, add a robots.txt file with the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigator gave a solution. 
Another solution is to use meta tags. 
Add this after you title in the HTML.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

More info : http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html